Is it grammatical to imply words from a parenthetical subordinate clause?
I stumbled over this sentence in the Guardian:

Dali’s case, while unique in its security failures, is not when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.

The meaning of the sentence is clear, the case is not unique when it comes to generalised bad airline travel behaviour.
I was under the impression though, that sentences are to make sense be valid when you remove subordinate clauses:

Dali’s case is not when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.

This is clearly missing an object. Given that this was not colloquial speech but written in an arguably reputable newspaper, is this an acceptable form?

The meaning of the sentence is clear It is not at all clear. There is no context. As it stands, I understood Dali as the famous artist "Salvador Dali" and "case" to mean a suitcase. The importance of context cannot be overstated.

I could try to find to the link to the original article to provide more context. However, it was just the name of a person in the story.

@Greybeard That’s not what “the meaning is clear” means – by the standard you’re applying here, virtually no sentence ever uttered is clear. I guessed at the painter as well, but that doesn’t change whether the sentence is clear: it doesn’t matter to the parsing of the sentence whether it’s Dali’s, Stalin’s or your aunt Ada’s case. I don’t see how you can possibly read case as referring to a suitcase, however: “Dali’s suitcase is unique in its security failures” is complete nonsense, whereas “The situation/occurrence relating to Dali is unique in its security failures” is meaningful.

Is it grammatical to imply that words come from a subordinate clause?

The sentence is uniquely bad in certain respects but not when it comes to generalized bad sentence behavior.

Could you provide an idea of what went before the sentence or at least a summary of it? It sounds as if it describes some sort of problem involving travel.  If this is so, then the word "case", would obviously refer to something to do with that travel problem, then the sentence makes clear sense.  Unlike other passengers, he had substantial security needs, but aggressive (or whatever) behaviour on airline flights is in general not at all  uncommon.

@Tuffy https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2024/dec/07/air-rage-unruly-passengers-crackdown
Previous sentence: "She later, allegedly, resisted efforts by French authorities efforts to return her to the US."
Context summary of previous paragraph: "A person named Svetlana Dali managed to sneak onto a passenger airplane, bypassing multiple levels of security, and was only spotted by a flight attendant when the plane was already landing."

It's fine! Ellipsis is fine coming and going... While [it is] unique in its security failures, the Dali situation is not [unique] when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.

@JanusBahsJacquet “Dali’s suitcase is unique in its security failures” is complete nonsense,. You are wrong. Given context, it is perfectly correct. As I needed the context for the example - you need context to understand "Dali’s suitcase is unique in its security failures." We are, in fact, in agreement on the principle of context.

You are correct. Surely, a sentence should make sense if the elaborative phrase were removed. The main reason for this rule is to avoid ambiguity that can arise from omitted parts of speech arising from the very application of implication. Imagine the below case:

Dali's destination is a pinnacle choice. Her case, however, while unique in its security failures, is not when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.

Now it doesn't make any sense. Is not what? This is the danger of relying on implication. You introduce to your writing the risk that the reader might infer the wrong meaning or no meaning at all. In this case, it's because the sentence's only clause is incomplete. It lacks the complement that is meant to be linked to the subject through the linking verb "is", leaving a diligent reader to wonder, "Is what?"
Sometimes, you can rely on verb disagreement to facilitate the implication, though I never would recommend it. The quote posted in the OP from The Guardian seems unprofessional to me and in fact carries a slight risk of misinterpretation especially by people whose primary language is not English and by lesser skilled readers. And for what? To save one word in the eternal quest to be more succinct? It's not a worthy tradeoff in my opinion.

I agree that the sentence is poorly written. It could have been improved by simply repeating "unique" or using a synonym:  "Dali’s case, while unique in its security failures, is not unprecedented when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour."

I'd strengthen 'Ideally a sentence should make sense if the elaborative phrase or other parenthetical [is] removed' to  'A sentence must make sense and have no change in overall meaning if the elaborative phrase or other parenthetical [is] removed'. This is in line with the usual 'definition' of parentheticals, and avoids the violation of the Gricean maxim of manner (clarity).  Here, the deletion is improper after the parenthetical usage ('unique'), and omission would be a worse error without a prior mention. // Can you give ...

a reference to the 'grammar rule' involved? (I'd say it is a semanto-syntactic rule, encompassing both allowable constructions and making sense. 'Chomsky's 'Colorless green ideas snore furiously' is impeccable from a grammatical standpoint. Famously so. But most English teachers would downmark it as ludicrous out of context.

Oops, I was only referring to the suggestion of the "rule" (presumably learned in school) that a sentence should stand even if you remove its introductory or elaborative phrase. Although I'm pretty sure this is a rule in at least two of the most authoritative style guides. I couldn't tell you as I no longer have subscriptions. (The irony...) I fixed the mention of "grammar rules" in an edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

This is completely and utterly wrong in every way.

@Shoe Do you not think it's the Dali out of context which throws the reader. Without that added strain (in the decontextualised example), the sentence seems ok to me.

@Araucaria-Him What is completely and utterly wrong, and why do you think so?

@Araucaria - Him. I wasn't thrown by "Dali", but of course whether the reader is thrown by a particular sentence depends on the reader's competence, background knowledge, etc. Careful writers anticipate when the reader may be momentarily confused and need to backtrack. The writer of the sentence in question has not done so. Hence my "poorly written" claim.

@Shoe How is it for you if the ellipted subject is reinserted into the while clause?  Dali’s case, while it is unique in its security failures, is not when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour. I ask because I'm trying to figure out exactly why ellipsis after not is troublesome (for many readers).

@Araucaria - Him. My stance on this is that any piece of writing that is considered problematic or even ungrammatical by a number of its readers is self-evidently 'troublesome'. Most writers would probably seek to avoid creating these kinds of negative responses. Inserting 'it' into the embedded concessive does not fix the problem for me. There's also a potential ambiguity issue with the its and it. Its refers to the case and it seems to be a dummy pronoun. I stand by my contention that this is not an unassailably constructed sentence.

You don't need to reference the noun "case" in the construction above because the "while" phrase is being used as a prepositional phrase here which unquestioningly refers to "case".

@Shoe I think you wildly misunderstand me! You write "My stance on this is that any piece of writing that is considered problematic or even ungrammatical by a number of its readers is self-evidently 'troublesome" But when I said "I'm trying to figure out exactly why the ellipsis after not is troublesome (for many readers).", I meant I was trying to figure out what technical aspect of the language caused the problem; i.e. what caused the misfiring re the intended referent of the ellipsis after not. No one's questioning it's troublesome - QED from Janus and others. Nothing to defend here!

@Araucaria-Him The reason why the ellipsis is confusing and potentially misleading is because the verb is a linking verb, "is", and because one noun can be the same or not the same as another noun. If a noun precedes the subject in a previous sentence, the ellipted object of this linking verb will be inferred by most readers to be that previously occurring noun. See my example in this answer: "Dali's destination is a pinnacle choice. Her case, however, while unique in its security failures, is not [a pinnacle choice] when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour."

There is a simple way of correcting the awkwardness of the sentence in question. There is a convention that in such a case, repetition of the relevant passage is avoided by the use of the adverb 'so' (meaning 'like that').  Thus you would have:

Dali’s case, while unique in its security failures, is not so when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.

Otherwise you would have to resort to repetition of the word 'unique'.
The repetition in this case makes relevant sense because of its brevity (what is the difference between two letters and and six between friends?  But if the repetition involved a lengthy clause or sentence, it would become more desirable.

Dali’s case, while unique in its security failures, is not [unique in its security failures] when it comes to generalized bad airline travel behaviour.
There is no need to repeat unique.
Not repeating the word unique or the entire phrase is an ellipsis and perfectly acceptable and understandable.

The sentence is fine as it stands. Who ever said that a main clause has to make sense if the subordinate clauses are taken out?

I like [that you came early today].
My idea is [that we'll make it up later], but Bob doesn't agree.
[What I can't stand] is [people taking time off during peak season].
[To make it on time] required a little ingenuity.
Steve recommended [taking the high road].
[While they're gone] is the perfect time to rob the place.

Also, that's not an object missing there, but a subject-oriented predicative complement. The verb be never takes objects, and an adjective phrase headed by unique can't be an object anyways, even under the most lax definitions of the term.
The acceptability of omitting words in the core of the main clause and leaving their interpretation, from a subordinate clause or adjunct, up to the reader depends heavily on the particular case.

[Though he said he'd come greet us], he didn't.
[While typically the absolute picture of health], that afternoon she was anything but.


I admit that "making sense" was the wrong choice of words. Judging by how you interpreted the question, it seems that "subordinate" clause it also not quite correct or at least I'm looking for a more specific term. While "My idea is" is a valid sentence that doesn't make sense, "required a little ingenuity" isn't one, because it's lacking the  subject. I hope you can guess what the appropriate label is for whatever I'm describing.

Both Greybeard and I were thrown; it's garden-pathy at the best. Also note that the inserted while-string must be considered a parenthetical insertion, and the matrix sentence (the rest) cannot stand alone. Yes, OP has not identified the question correctly, but your examples do not match the actual example.

I don’t understand what the point of your second sentence and the examples is. You say, implicitly, that a main clause doesn’t have to make sense if subordinate clauses are removed, and then you provide a number of examples where the main clauses do not make sense if the subordinate clauses are removed (e.g, “My idea is, but Bob doesn’t agree”). Plus, as Edwin says, the issue here is specifically with parentheticals, not just any subordinate clause, and their removability is indeed a defining feature of those.

@JanusBahsJacquet You've gone through this too quickly without considering what DW256 is saying. DW256 says implicitly that the idea that main clauses have to make sense when the subordinate one is taken out is suspect, and then gives examples where the main clause doesn't make sense with the subordinate clause taken out. DW256 is NOT contradicting themselves. Their point is exactly that the claim that sentences  should make sense with the subordinate clauses taken out is pre-eminently stupid - so detached from reality that it should make any sane reader throw their arms up in disgust

@EdwinAshworth I think it's garden-pathy primarily because of the "Dali", which we don't expect to be just a Smith or similar. If you substitute Smith in there, it's completely fine.

@JanusBahsJacquet I think DW256 deserves your upvote!

@JanusBahsJacquet No! It's saying main clauses CANNOT always work without their subordinate clauses. DW is saying  Who says that they can work without them, huh?

@Araucaria Gah, you’re right – the negations finally aligned  themselves properly in my head. But I stand by the fact that the woman’s name being Dali is completely irrelevant to the brokenness of the sentence. “Her case, while unique in X, is not when it comes to Y” is completely ungrammatical to me. It absolutely needs unique to be repeated in order to work. Rephrasing to avoid the parenthetical, “While her case is unique in X, it is not when it comes to Y” is grammatical, but still jars a bit due to the lack of parallel.

@JanusBahsJacquet How is it for you if the when it comes to is replaced by in?

@Araucaria If reordered (as per the edit to my comment above), perfectly grammatical: “While her case is unique in X, it is not in Y” is fine (though still more elegant with ‘it is not unique/so in Y’). Without the reordering, still ungrammatical.

@JanusBahsJacquet Interesting. They're both sound fine to me!
